# VLCのrubyバインディングを書いておりSegmentation faultが起きてしまいます

Tags: ruby

https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/05/ruby-ffi/ にあるコードを写経しています。

```rb
module VLC
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'vlc'
  attach_function :version, :libvlc_get_version, [], :string
  attach_function :new, :libvlc_new, [:int, :int], :pointer
  attach_function :libvlc_media_new_path, [:pointer, :string], :pointer
  attach_function :libvlc_media_player_new_from_media, [:pointer], :pointer
  attach_function :play, :libvlc_media_player_play, [:pointer], :int
  attach_function :stop, :libvlc_media_player_stop, [:pointer], :int
  attach_function :pause, :libvlc_media_player_pause, [:pointer], :int
end

vlc    = VLC.new(0, 0)
media  = VLC.libvlc_media_new_path(vlc, "/home/jesus/Downloads/meditation.mp3") # ここでエラー
```

```
=> #<FFI::Function address=0x000000010ac8c770>
irb(main):045:0> puts VLC.get_version
3.0.8 Vetinari
=> nil
irb(main):046:0>   vlc    = VLC.new(0, 0)
=> #<FFI::Pointer address=0x0000000000000000>
irb(main):047:0>   path = '/tmp/ffi/that.mp3'
=> "/tmp/ffi/that.mp3"
irb(main):048:0>   media  = VLC.libvlc_media_new_path(vlc, path)
(irb):48: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000018
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0037 p:---- s:0202 e:000201 CFUNC  :libvlc_media_new_path
c:0036 p:0015 s:0196 E:000ad8 EVAL   (irb):48 [FINISH]
c:0035 p:---- s:0192 e:000191 CFUNC  :eval
c:0034 p:0021 s:0184 e:000183 METHOD /Users/foo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/workspace.rb:85
[...]
```

https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga051342375370f3bf3821a537d4413435

bindingライブラリを書くのは初めて何を調べればいいかわかりません。どのようにデバッグすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: 可能性としてですが、「vlc コマンドがインストールされていないか、環境変数 `PATH` で指定されているディレクトリパスに vlc コマンドがない」ことが考えられます。こちらの環境は Ubuntu 20.04.1 ですが、vlc コマンドがインストールされていないと同様のエラー(`segmentation fault`)が発生します。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。このffiというgemを使ったコードは，vlcというファイル名の実行ファイルを環境変数PATH内からロードしているのでなく、パッケージマネージャが生成したdylibを読み込んでいます。

もし、ffi_libの引数に一致するdylibがないのであれば` Could not open library`が発生し、 `VLC.libvlc_get_version` には到達しないでしょう。

Comment: `brew cask install vlc` でインストールしたんですが、もしかしてbindingライブラリを作りために何かが足りない？
もしそうなら、どうすれば足りないパッケージをエラーログから探せるんでしょうか、、、。

Comment: 同じ環境で `python-vlc` は動いたのでライブラリは足りていそうでした。ffiを使わないで作ってみようと想います。